# Permutations when some objects are identical

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's say I need to find total number of words I can form by using the letters of the word "ROOT".

Since $2$ O's are present. They would arrange amongst themselves in $2!$ ways, so we have $2!-1$ ways being over-counted.

So my answer then would be $4! -(2!-1) = 23$

My question : Exactly what cases are still being over-counted?

Important Note : I'm aware that you need to divide $4!$ by $2!$ as each case is being counted $2!$ times. But this is not my question. 
**I want to know what exactly is going on with my first method.** I just can't seem to get a "feel" for it.

Thanks :)

Comment: _[..."] so we have 2!−1 ways being over-counted. ["]_: If you just say about O's, then yes. But it's $4\times 3$ ways be over-counted, in total.

Answer (score 1):

You forget about those partners of O's, that's the 'R' and 'T':

$$(\textrm{Choose position for R})(\textrm{ " for T})(2!-1),$$

so the part over-counted is

$$(4)(3)(2!-1)=12.$$

That is: you have to also think about how O's repetition *influences* the others.

---

For the case of type $ABAB$, as @Jürg Merlin Spaak  mension in the comment, then two separate steps are needed in this special case

(1) First see two A's as different

$$(\textrm{pos. for} A_1)(\textrm{pos. for}A_2)(\textrm{this part same idea as above}),$$

so

$$(4)(3)(2!-1)=12,$$

this is the part over-counted but what we want is $4!-12=12.$

(2) Now let's say they *are* identical:

$$(\textrm{ans from(1)})=(\textrm{other factors})(\textrm{factors of}A_1A_2)$$

so

$$12=(\textrm{other factors})(2!),$$

and $(\textrm{other factor})=12/2!=6$, now use the same idea

$$(\textrm{over-counted})=(\textrm{other factors=6})(2!-1)=6.$$

so total = $12-6=6.$

Comment: I don't think this is correct, as with the same logic you would get for MAMA: $(2-1)(2-1)=1$ possibilities.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak: I didn't say it apply to the case you given, my explanation works for this specific case since $4\times 3\times(2!-1)=total\times(1/2).$